# Bloquear todos puertos excepto algunos

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

Me gustaria permitir solo la entrada a un servidor publicado a Internet los puertos 22,80 y 443.
Lo estoy haciendo con las siguientes reglas:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
```

Ahora, me gustaría bloquear/denegar el resto.
Me estoy encontrando que si añado la siguiente regla algunos programas no funcionan correctamente.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j DROP
```

Por ejemplo, si reinicio Apache no me arranca. Parece que se queda en timeout.
En principio esta regla únicamente es de entrada, no?
O debería de poner otra regla?

Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

En general, hay trafico que se maneja en localhost que deberias dejar que vaya sin problemas. Adicionalmente, tienes que permitir que el trafico que el host inició, sus respuestas vengan sin problemas (por ejemplo, peticiones DNS). Te recomendaria 2 teglas mas para resolver el dilema:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT # permitir todo el trafico de localhost
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT # respuestas dns, icmp, etc etc
```

Ponerlas antes de la regla de drop que tienes en tu recetario. me pregunto si no te sería mejor colocar una *política* de DROP. En mi caso que no tengo reglas en el firewall:

```
$ sudo iptables -L INPUT -nv
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

La política se puede ver en la primera línea: `ACCEPT`. Se puede colocar con `iptables -P INPUT DROP` (tambien podría ser `REJECT`, que es diferente a `DROP`). La forma en la que se arman las reglas en el firewall es de las mas detalladas primero, a las mas generales después.... con la política siendo ya **the big hammer** al final (no al final de tus reglas, puede tener sentido colocar la política como la primera línea del recetario... para que no se escape ni el más mínimo paquete de tus reglas... es algo que tienes que sopesar. Me refiero *al final* porque si no hay ninguna regla que le diga a netfilter qué hacer con un paquete, se aplica la política... y siempre tener en cuenta que se toma lo que diga la primera línea que hace match con un paquete... y se revisan de una en una de arriba a abajo, por eso se recomienda escribirlas de las más específicas a las más generales).

Comment: Me ha funcionado! Sobre la política de DROP como la pondrías? entiendo que siempre debería de estar al final del todo por lo que se puede forzar a que esté al final?

Comment: Dejame explicar un poco mas en la respuesta.

Comment: si pongo "iptables -P INPUT DROP" se cierran los accesos. Por lo menos via SSH. Imagino que se pone al principio de todo

Comment: Claro, si lo estas configurando _a pie_ (no con un script) por ssh y lo primero que colocas es que el policy es DROP, obviamente que esa conexión no va a sobrevivir, no podras meter mas reglas y no vas a poder volver a conectarte al equipo. Pero si lo colocas todo en un script, en mi experiencia, puede ser que tengas una interrupción de quizás un par de segundos y luego vuelve a fluir (siempre y cuando coloques una regla para el trafico de ssh desde el que te estas conectando.. que si por puerto y por ip o solo por puerto, lo que consideres apropiado).

Comment: asi pues:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

Comment: Bien. Pero la última regla te la puedes ahorrar si colocas de policy DROP (así sea de última regla... en el sentido de comando).